# Use MaterialCheckBox with Material 2 app theme?

Tags: android, material-components-android

I still have not migrated to Material 3 and would like to use the indeterminate state in checkboxes which is [available on Material 3](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/checkbox/MaterialCheckBox.java) Is there a way to use this checkbox version without needing to use the Material 3 Theme? I tried it and only when my app's theme is Mateiral3 the indeterminate state can be shown, the other 2 states are shown with the Material2 theme but not the indeterminate state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this following line in your `MaterialCheckBox` view

```
android:theme="@style/Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
```